# Iframe based integration in Salesforce

Tags: iframe, salesforce, force.com

I want to show my site inside the Salesforce iFrame, and when someone does any activity on my site inside the iFrame i want to update the Salesforce page as well?

Can i do this, please suggest?

Comment: what do you mean by "Salesforce iFrame"? Are you using the iFrame on a VF page? or are you using the iFrame in a standard page layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more recent approach, now GA, is [Force.com Canvas](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Canvas) - this is iframe-based with additional security and features, including passing context such as Salesforce fields into the iframe.  It also enables the iframed web app to call Salesforce APIs based on that authentication, either via JavaScript or by your backend web app (Python, Java, etc) using the credentials from the Canvas framework.

You can also use the new Events feature within Canvas to send messages to the framing Salesforce page.

On authentication options: the Canvas Signed Request authentication is recommended and easy, but note that it doesn't give you a refresh token for OAuth2 - so if you need to do continuing background processing based on the user's authentication, you should use the Canvas OAuth2 authentication instead, which does give you a refresh token.

Overall, Canvas is cleaner than using a raw iframe and should simplify development. It does require some changes to authentication in the iframed web app but they are relatively simple (10 lines or so of Python).

Comment: Thanks RichVel. Canvas approach is looking good. I will check this out.

Comment: @techagrammer - good, have added a bit on authentication as well.  Upvotes are always an option of course :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript and page refreshing to send information to the parent window, but this isn't in my recommended books. iFrames are not meant to communicate with it's parent site for security reasons.

You might want to look into using an API to communicate between the two sites.

Comment: I agree with Luke here. Browser security will prevent you from communicating with the Salesforce page from within your iFrame. The best option you have is to utilize the Salesforce API to make updates to the system and then you can use javascript to tell the top level window to refresh itself.

Comment: His question doesn't specify the use case clearly. It is possible that he might not need the iFrame at all.

Comment: Using iframes directly in Salesforce is not a great idea - use Force.com Canvas instead, which is supported by Salesforce and provides authentication for free - a sort of "added value iframe".